# Restricting cipher suite on MSIE

Tags: tls, microsoft

I'm investigating significant performance problems with MSIE using TLS connections. I am trying to restrict the available algorithms to isolate the problem / see if there is valid workaround. To do this, I set the [SSL cipher suite preference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/prioritizing-schannel-cipher-suites) in the Group Policy Editor on the local machine to include only 2 AES128 based algorithms (I suspect the issue is in the asymmetric encryption, this was just to test if the method was valid). However when I apply the policy and start a new MIE instance, it still uses an AES256 suite - i.e. not on on the list I specified.

Its MSIE 11 on MS Server 2012R2.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How to configure Windows or IE (even for TLS settings) seems off-topic here?

Comment: Maybe - but I was expecting a more capable audience here than on superuser or serverfault (where I've seen similar questions and the quality of the answers)

Comment: While I appreciate that you think that the more capable people are here, we do have to keep the subject areas in the correct areas.

Comment: Also note that you're probably not far off in your assessment on the asymmetric crypto.  MS has had significant problems with single-threading high volumes of asymmetric operations.  As an example, if you require signing of network communications (e.g. file server and workstation), and you push a large file, you'll notice horrendous transfer speeds. And this is because SMB is digitially signing each packet with a single thread.  Turn it off and you'll see your speeds increase by at least an order of magnitude.  2008 has a patch nothing after does -- thanks MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice this little message on the microsoft article you posted??:

> It is necessary to restart the computer after modifying this setting
>   for the changes to take effect.

You also didn't mention it but have you checked to ensure the setting is actually applying?

```
gpresult /h policy.html
```

Comment: Doh! Sometimes its the simple things. Interestingly it turns out the problem is not the SSL, but rather that Microsoft's DNS client applies non-standard processing to the resolution of of CRL server hostname.